# Loop through dictionary and save each dataframe in the dict as a csv?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe that looks like the following but with thousands of rows of data

```
ID#  Segment Sub-Segment Account Manager Name
1234 America Midwest     Walmart Bobby Jindal
4567 America Midwest     Target  Bobby Jindal
5678 America Northeast   Dunkin  Peter Thiel
```

My end goal is to create a separate data frame for each unique value in the Manager Name column and label the dataframe as the Manager's name. So the above dataset would output two dfs

So I decided to create a dict and have now created unique dataframes but the problem I am encountering now is that I want to save each dataframe as a csv with the naming convention being the Manager Name so "Bobby Jindal.csv"

```
df_sliced={}
for name in df['Manager Name'].unique():
    df_sliced[name]=df[df['Manager Name']==name]
```

I'm not sure what the next step is to save each dataframe in the dict as a csv. Can you please assist with this and help with syntax?

Comment: why are you storing the frames in `df_sliced`? Is it just to save them, or is there another use later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `to_csv` ad the end of your loop:

```
df_sliced={}
for name in df['Manager Name'].unique():
    df_sliced[name]=df[df['Manager Name']==name]
    df_sliced[name].to_csv(f'{name}.csv', index=False)
```

```
>>> %cat Bobby\ Jindal.csv
ID#,Segment,Sub-Segment,Account,Manager Name
1234,America,Midwest,Walmart,Bobby Jindal
4567,America,Midwest,Target,Bobby Jindal

>>> %cat Peter\ Thiel.csv
ID#,Segment,Sub-Segment,Account,Manager Name
5678,America,Northeast,Dunkin,Peter Thiel
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your code further with the following:

```py
for name, g in df.groupby('Manager Name'):
    g.to_csv(f'{name}.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas.to_csv`:

```
for name in df_sliced:
    df_sliced[name].to_csv(f"{name}.csv")
```

If you want to save the csv to somewhere other than the current working directory, specify the full path in `to_csv` like: `df_sliced[name].to_csv(f"C:/folder/subfolder/{name}.csv")`